# Error al enviar de datos a través de ajax a php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Estoy tratando de enviar una variable a través de un ajax a php pero por alguna razón no recibe los datos.

Esta es mi función ajax

```
function cargaDatos(val = 2){
    try {
        $.ajax(
          { 
            data: {id: val,},
            url: 'AgregarTarjetas.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (r) {
              ChangePage1(r)
            },
          });
      } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
      }
}
```

y este mi código php

```
<?php
$hola = $_POST["id"];
echo $hola;
$conn = oci_connect('ProyectoLBD', 'ProyectoLBD', 'orcl');
$sql = 'BEGIN seleccionar(:registros,:codigo); END;'; 
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$paramIn = 1;
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,":codigo",$paramIn,-1,SQLT_INT);
$rs = oci_new_cursor($conn);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,":registros",$rs,-1,OCI_B_CURSOR);
oci_execute($stmt);
oci_execute($rs);
$mData=array();
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($rs)) {   
   $mData[] = $row;   
}
echo json_encode($mData);
```

?>

como ven no he implementado el uso de la variable solo la estoy imprimiendo para saber si se llega a recibir.

Comment: En tu navegador, en la parte de red, se lleva a cabo la solicitud? Por otro lado, no es necesario colocar el `try-catch` por AJAX tiene su propio manejor de errores. Ya que la estructura en realidad deberia ser asi: `success: function (r) { ... }, error: function(xhr, status) {  ...  }`

Comment: Bajo que nombre debería de aparecer en la parte de red?

Comment: Como dice @JuanRivera, las peticiones Ajax de jQuery tienen su propio manejo de error, te recomiendo que estandarices el código en ese sentido. Luego, en PHP, el echo que tienes al principio te va a romper el JSON, por lo que deberías quitarlo. Por último, no has depurado nada. Pon un `console.log(r);` en la parte del success y activa la consola para ver si tu petición está funcionando o hay algún error.

Comment: Tienen razón mi solicitud no se lleva acabo, anteriormente ese Ajax solo hacia el llamado a la pagina PHP y si recolectaba la información pero ahora no hace nada